# this is referencing the whole window rather than the element in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, this, typeerror, tic-tac-toe

I am new to javascript and was trying to practice what I know by building a tic-tac-toe game.

> I have created a grid in the HTML and am trying to record the player's
>   move by changing the block, that is clicked, to an X or O by adding a class name to it. I am also saving the position of the clicked block and in the end checking if the last move led to a win or not, using the *winCheck* function.

Below is the part of the code that raises the error:

```js
    const square = document.querySelectorAll('.square')
    // playing : x starts
    let player = 'x'

    square.forEach(block=>{
        block.addEventListener('click', play(player))
    })

    function play(player) {
        if(!search(this.id,occupied)){
            occupied.push(this.id)
            if(player==='x'){
                this.classList.add('x')
                player = 'o'
                x.push(this.id)
            }else if(player==='o'){
                this.classList.add('o')
                player = 'x'
                o.push(this.id)
            }
            winCheck()
        }
    }
```

error raised :

```
TypeError: this.classList is undefined
```

When I did a *console.log(this)* inside the *play* function I saw that it was referencing the complete window( document or DOM or *the right word that I don't know because I am new to front-end development* )

> I am sorry if the question lacks detail, hard to frame a question on the topic you don't know

Comment: This is contextual, so it will change depending on where you call it. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish in terms of expected behavior?

Comment: @JoelHager I am trying to record the player's move by changing the block that clicks to an X or O. I am also saving the position of the click and running a Check if the last move led to a win or not, in the end, using the winCheck. Hope the edits help

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would do is add just one event listener to the document, then work with the event itself. There's no point in attaching an event listener to every single square when one would do the trick.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // then you want to make sure that the target of the event is one of your squares
    if (event.target.classList.contains('square')) {
        //you want to handle the event here, so to prevent further bubbling
        event.stopPropagation();
        //then start manipulating the appearance of your square
    }
});
```

The `this` keyword in Javascript can get quite confusing at the early stages of development. I'd avoid it until you're comfortable with the basics and ready to move on to more complex stuff.

Comment: I did not know about the event.target attribute, will look into it. Does it return the HTML block(the innermost, outermost or something) where the event occured.?

Comment: Yes it will. There's a complication in that usually events 'bubble' up through the document. So the event will fire for the smallest item under the point of the click, then bubble up through the containers until it reaches the body element, then the html element. You don't need to worry about that in this simple example but it's worth researching. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation

Comment: Couldn't he use stopPropagation() to prevent bubbling?

Comment: Yes, that would probably be wise. I'll add it to the example

Answer (score 1):

You writing code of Vanilla JS, but you mixing the concept of jQuery and Vanilla JS.

Your function `play()` is event function, actually the parameter `player` passed in is the `event` itself.

So you should:

- Rename the parameter `player` to `event`.
- The `player` element should be `event.currentTarget`
- And `this` of cause should set to `player` by yourself (if you want to use it)